# Why does the classical Doppler formula make a distinction between movement of the source and movement of the receiver?

Tags: waves, relative-motion, doppler-effect

I've tried rewriting the Doppler formula to include only the relative velocity between the source and the receiver of sound waves. However, when I compare the results with the results of the formula that includes "velocity of the receiver" and "velocity of the source", they are not the same. Is that because the medium (the air) constitutes an absoulte reference frame when it comes to sound waves or is there a different explanation?

Comment: You should be able to reduce the [general Doppler-shift formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Systematic_derivation_for_inertial_observers) down to the [classical approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) (in a frame where either the observer or source are at rest relative to the medium) if do things correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. Imagine a sound emitter and receiver traveling at twice the speed of sound in the same direction with the emitter behind the receiver. Even though the relative velocity is zero, the sound will never reach the receiver because sound doesn't travel fast enough. At this point, the frequency calculated from Doppler shift formulas would have either diverged or gone negative, indicating a problem with reception.

Light in a vacuum, on the other hand, has a different formula precisely because there is no absolute reference frame. Here, only relative velocities matter.